# Raphael is "not defined" when using Raphael.fn

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to use Raphael.fn is an external JavaScript .js file.  I am also debugging with FireBug on FireFox 20.0.

```
Canvas.paper = Raphael(xOffset,yOffset,imageWidth,imageHeight);
```

works fine but

```
Raphael.fn.arrow = function (x1, y1, x2, y2, size) {
    // Code
};
```

gives an error message of

```
Raphael is not defined
```

in Firebug.

Comment: Check if `rapheal.js` is included/ran before your code.

Comment: Yes.  It seems that was the problem. I had included rapheal.js in the head section of the the html file but only after I had included my own .js file which was generating the error.  After moving the rapheal.js inclusion to before my own .js file inclusion made the problem go away.  I am still perplexed that "Canvas.paper = Raphael(xOffset,yOffset,imageWidth,imageHeight);" still worked with the inclusion around the wrong way.  Thank you very much for your help.